# linq index out of bounds

Tags: c#, linq, list, indexoutofboundsexception

In my friend's code, he has a `List`:

```
 List<int> listOfIds = new List<int>();
```

Then I used `AddRange()` to add a collection of int to it:

```
   listOfIds.AddRange(this._employeeList
                       .Where(r => r.EmployeeID != null)
                       .Select(r => r.EmployeeID != null ? r.EmployeeID.Value : 0));
```

But then, in the logs, it said:

```
 System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.InsertRange(Int32 index, IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at the method which called the codes above.....
```

I am not really sure why this happened. I am pretty sure this error happened on the code above but I cant seem to understand why an `IndexOutofRangeException` would come up.

Can you help me point out which can cause this?

**UPDATE:**

I am wrong. I am very sorry. The method does not use multithreading. BUT, another method which called this method is using Parallel.Foreach, which means multithreading. It might be possible that while the _employeeList is being used as a source for the AddRange(), another thread is also modifying it. Thus, the answer that the addrange() is not thread-safe is plausible. THANK YOU SO MUCH GUYS.

Comment: It sounds like you're using it from multiple threads.

Comment: Try this code: listOfIds.AddRange(this._employeeList
                       .Where(r => r.EmployeeID != null)
                       .Select(r => r.EmployeeID != null ? r.EmployeeID.Value : 0).ToList())

Comment: Your `Where` and `Select` don't match up.  your `EmployeeID` can never be null because your `Where` filters that out.  Do you really want `0` to be added to your list if the ID is null?

Comment: @Roman, whats the help of ToList()?

Comment: Just try. Mine guessing is that You use LINQ query instead of collection with data.When You invoke .ToList() query executes only once, not every time with .Next() (AddRange works with IEnumerable)

Comment: guys, I know that the where clause will already filter the employeeids. what i cant get is how an index out of range exception comes up in this.

Comment: What is the type of `_employeeList`?

Comment: list of Employee (a class) objects which have an EmployeeId property

Comment: What is the complete error stack? You say that you think this is where the error is being generated, but that doesn't sound very positive and I don't see any indexes being used explicitly in the code provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to tell more concrete ideas, but this might work.

`AddRange` is not thread-safe. Try to use `lock primitives` to add many items. Declare:

```
private static object mutex = new object();
```

Usage

```
lock(mutex)
{
    listOfIds.AddRange( /* code goes here */ )
}
```

After decompilation of `AddRange` found

```
public void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> collection)
{
  this.InsertRange(this._size, collection);
}
```

Contents of `InsertRange`, which you can see on stack trace:

```
  ...
  ICollection<T> collection1 = collection as ICollection<T>;
  if (collection1 != null)
  {
     ...
  }
  else
  {
    foreach (T obj in collection)
      this.Insert(index++, obj);
  }
```

In other words - it iterates over sequence and tries to add item by item using **incremented index**. This shouldn't go wrong, should it?. `845` line in `List.cs` decompiled by `dotPeek`. So I wouldn't trust the stack trace, except I would see the whole one.

Comment: The line `System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator'2.MoveNext()` in the stack trace is suggesting, error is coming in Where clause

Comment: @Tilak But the top method in the stack is just a plain `MoveNext` call on a `List`.

Comment: @Rawling: Noted. I was looking at probably wrong direction. Still i believe problem is in Linq Query deferred execution and not in AddRange itself (Having known that multithreading is not involved)

Comment: I am wrong. I am very sorry. The method does not use multithreading. BUT, another method which called this method is using Parallel.Foreach. Thus, the answer that the addrange() is not thread-safe is plausible. THANK YOU SO MUCH GUYS.

Comment: you can never count on assumption, that code is being single-threaded) Cheers.